# Codeigniter : Compare two dates and show it on a table with listing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to compare two dates and show them front of my article

difference date example.
ArtOne ( +2Hours ) | 10/10/2019  | something

SQl

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PERSONNE_A_LIVRER` text NOT NULL,
  `ETAT` text NOT NULL,
  `DATE_TRANSPORT` text NOT NULL,
  `DATE_LIVRER` text NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

DATE_TRANSPORT = 01/10/2019 11:38
DATE_LIVRER    = 02/10/2019 11:38
...

All i want to know diff in hoours in in a column.
here is my model,

```php
    public function select_all() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

        $data = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $data->result();
    }
```

code of my Controller

```php
    public function listart() {
        $data['dataPegawai'] = $this->M_pegawai->select_all();
        $this->load->view('pegawai/list_data', $data);
    }

    function differenceInHours($startdate,$enddate) {
        $starttimestamp = strtotime($startdate);
        $endtimestamp = strtotime($enddate);
        $difference = abs($endtimestamp - $starttimestamp)/3600;
        return $difference;
    }
```

code of my view html and php

```html
<?php
  foreach ($dataPegawai as $albat) {
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:90px;">
      <?php echo $albat->PERSONNE_A_LIVRER ; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->N_LIVRAISON;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $hours_difference = differenceInHours($albat->DATE_EXP,$albat->DATE_TRANSPORT);?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->DESTINATAIRE;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->DIRECTION_A_LIVRER ;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->DESCRIPCION_ETAT;?>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" style="min-width:90px;">

      <button class="btn default konfirmasiHapus-articulo"> List it </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
?>
```

and thanks in advance

Comment: i did tried but it doesnt work for me .

Comment: Hey Nijland 
can you help by editing code above if it's possible as i am not prof in codeigniter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example you want to compare both `DATE_EXP` and `DATE_TRANSPORT` value, you could call the `differenceInHours()` function on the controller instead, not on the view, because it's a good practice to keep the view for presentation only.

Modify the controller like this :

```php
    public function listart() {
        $data['dataPegawai'] = $this->M_pegawai->select_all();
        foreach ($data['dataPegawai'] as $key => $value) {
            $startdate = $value->DATE_EXP;
            $enddate = $value->DATE_TRANSPORT;
            $data['dataPegawai']->$key->hourDifference = $this->differenceInHours($startdate, $enddate);
        }
        $this->load->view('pegawai/list_data', $data);
    }

    function differenceInHours($startdate,$enddate) {
        $starttimestamp = strtotime($startdate);
        $endtimestamp = strtotime($enddate);
        $difference = abs($endtimestamp - $starttimestamp)/3600;
        return $difference;
    }
```

And the view like this :

```php
<?php
  foreach ($dataPegawai as $albat) {
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:90px;">
      <?php echo $albat->PERSONNE_A_LIVRER ; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->N_LIVRAISON;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->hourDifference;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->DESTINATAIRE;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->DIRECTION_A_LIVRER ;?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $albat->DESCRIPCION_ETAT;?>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" style="min-width:90px;">

      <button class="btn default konfirmasiHapus-articulo"> List it </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try it right now and tell you !!

Comment: i have error message undefined ' hourDifference '
the line with (       <?php echo $albat->hourDifference;?> ) not recognised.

Comment: @abdelghani let me know if you still have a problem

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Could you do `print_r($data);die();` before this line `$this->load->view('pegawai/list_data', $data);` and show the result of it?

Answer (score 0):

now i've tried this and it doesn't work, it shows me error message as follows :

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: hourDifference

My controller i edited

```
public function tampil() {
    $data['dataPegawai'] = $this->M_pegawai->select_all();
    foreach ($$data['dataPegawai'] as $item => $value) {
        $D1 = $value->OBSERVATION;
        $D2 = $value->DATE_TRANSPORT;
        $data['dataPegawai']->$key->$hourDifference = $this->differenceInHours($startdate, $enddate);
    }
    $this->load->view('pegawai/list_data', $data);
}
```

and then i called those to my view as follows :

```
<?php
  foreach ($dataPegawai as $albatr) {
    ?>
    <tr>
          <td><?php echo $albatr->$hourDifference;?> </td><!-- -->
      <td class="text-center" style="min-width:230px;">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check-sign"></i> Check </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
  }
?>
```

Any Help !

Comment: Just so you know, I didn't write `$key->$hourDifference` but `$key->hourDifference`, notice the `$` sign

Comment: still have the same problem,
i got this msg : Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$hourDifference